# Map.entry and entrySet() generic type goes wrong

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Here is the gone-wrone code

`Set<Map.Entry> entrySet = new HashMap<Object,Object>().entrySet();`

it comes up with a compile error

`cannot convert from Set<Map.Entry<Object,Object>> to Set<Map.Entry>`

But there should be just a warning from not using generic type in the case  `Map.Entry` from `Map.Entry<Object,Object>`
But why here come out a compile error?
then I've suspected that the whole `Set<Map.Entry>` may be the reason,that is maybe `Set<Map.Entry>` ≠ `set<Map.Entry<Object,Object>`
but since `Map.Entry` ≈ `Map.Entry<Object,Object>`
why not `Set<Map.Entry>` ≈ `set<Map.Entry<Object,Object>`

I've find the relavent questions,but my question is this case is something different.
To be more spacific,why when I use `Set<Map.Entry>`,I can't event get through compile and get an error but not just a warning?
But in another case,for example`ArrayList li = new ArrayList<String>();`
I can get through compile and just get a warning "ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList should be 
     parameterized"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1553851)

Comment: See also [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1553851)

Comment: Thanks,I've find the relavent questions,but my question is this case is something different.
To be more spacific,why when I use Set<Map.Entry>,I can't event get through compile and get an error but not just a warning?
But in another case,for exampleArrayList li = new ArrayList<String>();
I can get through compile and just get a warning "ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList should be parameterized"

Comment: That's answered in the second link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because  of the set<> generic type.For example,
`HashSet<String> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>` may goes wrong.
If the right side is a Integer generic type instance,then the reference variable's generic type in the left side cannot be String.
so `String ≠ Integer` like `Map.Entry ≠ Map.Entry<Object,Object>`